# Is it true that Vedas direct people to give birth to 10 sons?

Tags: vedas, marriage, children

Is it true that Vedas direct people [to give birth to 10 sons](https://youtu.be/DLpGFzdNDjk?t=419) ?
Does the veda also tell people that [it is better not to give birth to anyone than giving birth to just one son](https://youtu.be/DLpGFzdNDjk?t=419) ?

Comment: '10 sons' - yes, as a guideline/blessing, not an order. 'better 0 than 1' - again, it's a phrase of speech like 'it's better to be dead than live with 1 leg'. the reason for saying these is that having more progeny means more joy, more peace of mind, more wealth etc.